# Code Compiling Error, boolean in java?

Tags: java

I was just wondering if I could please have some help in trying to fix this public boolean method, I can't get this code to compile, please can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? thanks

//This is the method before which is compiling correctly, but the next boolean method is an opposite of this one, where the error occurs.

```
public void uncover(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
    if (areIndexesValid(thisCol, thisRow)) {
        is_hidden[thisCol][thisRow] = false;
    }
}
```

//This is the boolean that needs fixing.

```
public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
        // TODO check the indexes.  If not valid, then return false else      return
        if (areIndexesValid(thisCol, thisRow)) {
        return is_hidden[thisCol][thisRow]  
        else 
        return false
    }
```

}

Comment: You don't have semi-colons on either of your return statements...

Comment: now up-vote the correct answer below. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: @AmitG He can't upvote yet.

Comment: @user2175379 - Plus you have *unbalanced* curly braces.

Comment: The errors are come away via editors. Good job.

Comment: @Vitthal the typo you fixed in OP was indeed one of the issue.

Comment: What I'm interesting is why `areIndexesValid` has only two parameters?

Comment: @user2175379, which editor are you using?  any editor will catch the semicolons or the error message will indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer it like this:

```
public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
    return areIndexesValid(thisCol, thisRow) && is_hidden[thisCol][thisRow]; 
}
```

Comment: Much nicer, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  In fact, your compile error will tell you what's going on.  Read that and fix the line causing the problem.

Secondly I recommend using an IDE such as Eclipse.  It will put a red squiggly line under your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
        // TODO check the indexes.  If not valid, then return false else      return
        if (areIndexesValid(thisCol, thisRow)) 
            return is_hidden[thisCol][thisRow] ; 
        else 
            return false;
    }
```

(you had an excess {)

The reason it was complaining is twofold:

1. Your syntax is wrong
2. Any method which returns a value in Java MUST return a value on all paths. This code

   ```
   public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow) {

       // TODO check the indexes.  If not valid, then return false else      return
       if (areIndexesValid(thisCol, thisRow)) 
          return is_hidden[thisCol][thisRow] ; 

   }
   ```

would return a syntax error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement does not belong to any `if`. I guess this is also what the compiler said.

Here is how it should look like:

```
if (areIndexesValid(thisCol, thisRow)) {
    return is_hidden[thisCol][thisRow];
} else 
    return false;
```

i think you need to read something about [if statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).